# Getting invalid authorization_code, error AADSTS70000: The provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid. The code has expired

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using an Office 365 Family account, and getting an incorrect authorization code back, using the following url:

```
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[CLIENT ID]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20Calendars.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.All%20User.Read%20openid%20profile&state=12345';
```

The code I received on one attempt was: `M.R3_BAY.44e411b5-8fcf-f0be-2356-d56fd3293055`, and they all have that format whenever I try, which is not what it should be like, and does not decode on jwt.

Can anyone please tell me what's going wrong? I've been searching for months for an answer without any luck.

Comment: Try to change `common` to `tenant id`.

Comment: Yeah, as @CarlZhao said, try with tenantid. Let us know if it works or not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, tried that with no luck.

Comment: Is your application a multi-tenant application?

Comment: What if you use v1.0 endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`.

Comment: @CarlZhao this is the response I got using v1.0: `AADSTS500202: User account '{EmailHidden}' from external identity provider 'live.com' is not supported for API version '2.0'. Microsoft account pass-thru users and guests are not supported by the tenant-independent endpoint.`

Comment: Is your account a guest?

Comment: @CarlZhao the application is multi-tenant, and the user account is not a guest. I want all accounts from any tenants to be able to use it.

Comment: I've tried your url to login in and got correct code. And I assume that it may relate to your application. Have you tried other user accounts to check if the problem resulted from user  or the app you used?

Comment: @Tiny-wa it works with any work or school account with Exchange, but not with free personal or Office 365 Family subscriptions.

I thought v2.0 is supposed to accept these accounts as well, but it doesn't. What kind of account did you use?

Comment: I tried to use an azure ad account within my tenant and another is external my tenant. That's a little different with your accounts. Because my account has no Exchange license.

Comment: @Tiny-wa what kind of account

Comment: Work account with O365 E3 license. But I think it has no relationship with your case.

Comment: @Tiny-wa like I said above, I've tried with a few work accounts and they all work. But, it doesn't work with Office 365 Family or free accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the authorization code, it is not meant to be decoded.
You are supposed to exchange it for tokens, which are in JWT format.
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token

If this is in fact an access token, it could be for a personal Microsoft account. I've seen different format tokens there before.
You currently allow all Office 365 accounts *and* personal Microsoft accounts since you use `common` endpoint on v2.0.
If you only mean to support all Office 365 accounts, you can use `organizations` instead.

Comment: No this is not the access token. This is the authorisation code I get back when the user (Office 365 Family account) is directed to the authorisation url above, which is then used to get access and refresh tokens. And yes, you're right, the authorisation code is not supposed to be in JWT format, my mistake. And also, I want to allow all types of accounts, which is why I used `common`.

Comment: @Sofistikat did you resolved this issue, i am also facing the same issue, if you have found the solution, can you please share here.?

Comment: @Nagaraj M no, I never did, and I looked everywhere for a solution. In the end, I just decided to let users know they need a paid O365 subscription to be able to use my integration.

Comment: @Sofistikat thanks for the reply, i got it, it seems this is something broken from Microsoft side, many users facing this issue you can find the details in this official Microsoft forum
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/400-bad-request-undefinedscope-profilebadrequestexception-on/m-p/2421960#M6427

Comment: @NagarajM I know, I posted there as well, and some Microsoft experts tried to help, but were just as confused as I was, because the API is supposed to work for all kinds of Office users, including free & family accounts. But obviously, that is not the case.